# Bind dxSelectBox on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, devexpress, devextreme

I am using DevExtreme MVVM architecture and According to my scenario when button click event I need to bind the dxSelectBox (combo box).

HTML CODE:

```
<div data-bind="dxButton:{onClick:display,text:'Click Me'}"></div>

<div data-bind="dxSelectBox:{dataSource: themes, displayExpr: 'name' }"></div>
```

JS CODE:

```
var themesArray = [
        { themeId: 1, name: "Android (Dunkel)" },
        { themeId: 2, name: "Desktop" },
        { themeId: 3, name: "iOS" },
        { themeId: 4, name: "Windows 8" },
        { themeId: 5, name: "Windows Phone 8" },
        { themeId: 6, name: "Tizen" }
];

var themes = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(themesArray);

var viewModel = {
    themes: '',
    display: function () {
        console.log(themesArray);
        themes: themesArray
    }
};
return viewModel;
```

HINT: dxSelectBox has empty value...
I am new to this environment and I don't know where I did mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you forgot to set the 'value' option, e.g.:

```
data-bind="dxSelectBox: { dataSource: [ { val: true, text: 'Yes' }, { val: false, text: 'No' }], valueExpr: 'val', displayExpr: 'text', value: visible }"
```

For your context:

```
var viewModel = {
themes: [ ...array of themes... ],
selectedThemeId: 1,
display: function () {
    console.log(themesArray);
    themes: themesArray
}
};

data-bind="dxSelectBox: { dataSource: themes, valueExpr: 'themeId', displayExpr: 'name', value: selectedThemeId }"
```

I tired the following code:

```
 var themesArray = [
        { themeId: 1, name: "Android (Dunkel)" },
        { themeId: 2, name: "Desktop" },
        { themeId: 3, name: "iOS" },
        { themeId: 4, name: "Windows 8" },
        { themeId: 5, name: "Windows Phone 8" },
        { themeId: 6, name: "Tizen" }
   ];

  var modifiedthemesArray = [
      { themeId: 1, name: "a (Dunkel)" },
      { themeId: 2, name: "b" },
      { themeId: 3, name: "c" },
      { themeId: 4, name: "Windows 8" },
      { themeId: 5, name: "Windows Phone 8" },
      { themeId: 6, name: "Tizen" }
  ];

  var themes = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(themesArray);

  var viewModel = {
    themes: themesArray,
    selectedThemeId: 1,
    display: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        themes: modifiedthemesArray
    }
 };
  return viewModel;
```

You can use [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) to change collection object. I tired the following code and it works for me:

```
 var themesArray = [
    { themeId: 1, name: "Android (Dunkel)" },
    { themeId: 2, name: "Desktop" },
    { themeId: 3, name: "iOS" },
    { themeId: 4, name: "Windows 8" },
    { themeId: 5, name: "Windows Phone 8" },
    { themeId: 6, name: "Tizen" }
    ];

    var viewModel = {
        themes: ko.observableArray(),
        display: function() {
            console.log(themesArray);
            viewModel.themes(themesArray);
        }
    };

    return viewModel;
```

Comment: Thanks for spending time with this... At the button click[display()] only, bind the value until it empty..

Comment: Not sure that i understand you right, the model is accessible via argument of the onClick handler, see http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxButton/Configuration/?version=14_2#onClick for more details - e.model

Comment: You can use the onChange handler of the dxSelectBox: http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxSelectBox/Configuration/?version=14_2#onChange

Comment: Is it possible to update the datasource(themesArray) and assign it in display function, whether that updated datasource get bind or not.

Comment: By simple I need to bind the updated datasource in dxSelectBox via On Change or button click whatever it may... Even I tired with onChange but updated datasource not get affected..

Comment: If you can use knockout and put itmes into ko.observableArray, then dxSelectBox will update the list. I'll try to involve more experienced person into this discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67462/discussion-between-sona-and-tsv).